# How can I get simple Lightbox to show that scaling effect when hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, python, django, lightbox

I have little experience with javascript and I am now building a little site with Django. Then I stumbled upon a site that mentioned SimpleLightbox.

So, here is what I got:

```
{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    {% static "../" as baseURL %}
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'photo/css/simple-lightbox.min.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photo/js/simple-lightbox.jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photo/js/simple-lightbox.js' %}"></script>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
        <h2 class="page-header-tuesday">Bilder Galerie</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-7 col-md-offset-0 text-mainframe">
                <br>
                <div class="gallery">
                    {% load photo_tags %}
                        {% if images %}
                            {% for image in images %}
                                {% with image|split:'.' as strs %}
                                {% with strs|length as str_arr_len %}
                                {% with str_arr_len|add:'-1' as ext_idx %}
                                {% if strs|get_by_index:ext_idx == 'jpg' %}
                                <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL}}ObjPDW2/bilder/{{ image }}">
                                    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}ObjPDW2/bilder/{{ image }}" alt="{{ image }}">
                                    </a>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endwith %}
                                {% endwith %}
                                {% endwith %}
                                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            <p>No image available.</p>
                        {% endif %}
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var lightbox = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1">
                    <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
{% endblock %}
```

I can see the test image that I have in the folder. And when I follow the links to photo/css/simple-lightbox.min.css' and photo/js/simple-lightbox.jquery.min.js the source code is displayed correctly.
However, I just see a normal image when I visit my site. When I hover over the image there is no scaling effect. When I click on the image, then the image is just displayed and nothing of these fancy lightbox things. So the site behaves as if there was no lightbox present and I would just have a  code.

How could I find out what goes wrong?

**Edit**
Now I have added two more js files. I do not really know how to handle web developer functions in Firefox, but at least I found a debugger that now says on page reload:"Paused on exception
SyntaxError: Element.querySelectorAll: '\' is not a valid selector"

Answer (score 0):

Solved by rearranging the order of js and css includes and putting it all at the end of the site.